# Kivy on Android get bluetooth state

Tags: android, python-3.x, bluetooth, kivy, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get my app to get all paired devices after programmatically enabling the bluetooth.  The thing is Android only allows you getting all paired devices if the bluetooth `state` is on.  Now I already have a pop up that pops up if there is no bluetooth which has an option to enable bluetooth successfully calling `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().enable()`.

The thing is this enable call runs slow and if my subsequent line code checks for enabled state, it over runs before getting all paired devices:

```py
    if BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().isEnabled(): 
        this.root.get_devices()
```

Therefore I tried the broadcast receiver implementation from the [p4a docs](http://inclem.net/files/p4a_revamp_doc/old_toolchain/android.html#module-android.broadcast) :

```py
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        if platform == 'android':
            self.intent_bltooth = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
            self.br = BroadcastReceiver(self.on_broadcast, actions=['state_changed'])
            self.stream = Stream()
            self.br.start()
    def on_broadcast(self, context, intent):
        print(intent.getAction(), 'see intent action')
        listen = intent.getExtras()
        bltooth_state = bool(listen.get('state'))
        if bltooth_state:
            this.root.get_devices()
            print('bluetooth connected')
        else:
            print('bluetooth not connected')
```

But this gives me a constant `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED intent does not exist`.

So to overcome this I decided to use a more pure kivy solution in the form of a `trigger` that checks the bluetooth state until enabled:

```py
    def enable_bluetooth(self, *args):
        this = App.get_running_app()
        if platform == 'android':
            blueAdapt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

            blueAdapt.enable()
        this.root.dialog_with_action.remove_action_button()
        self.bluet_ticker() # this line gives the error TypeError: Argument 'obj' has incorrect type (expected kivy._event.EventDispatcher, got BluetoothHelper)
    def bluet_ticker(self):
        print('one tick')
        self.bluet_tme = 1000
        print('two tick')
        self.bluet_tick = Clock.create_trigger(lambda dt: self.run_bluet_ticker(), 0)
        print('three tick')
        self.bluet_tick()
    def run_bluet_ticker(self):
        this = App.get_running_app()
        blueAdapt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
        if self.bluet_tme > 0:
            if blueAdapt.isEnabled() == False:
                print('not ennnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnbled')
                self.bluet_tme -= 1
                self.bluet_tick()
            else:
                this.root.get_devices()
                print('ennnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnabling bbluuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuutoottttttth')
                self.bluet_tick.cancel()
        else:
            self.bluet_ticker()
```

But when the trigger function `bluet_trigger()` is called I get the following error: `TypeError: Argument 'obj' has incorrect type (expected kivy._event.EventDispatcher, got BluetoothHelper)`

Can someone please assist in either helping to point me in the right direction to find a solution to use a `BroadcastReceiver` or the `trigger`?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer I found from user with alias AdyWizard on discord and his project [wifiscan](https://github.com/adywizard/wifiscan)

So the off the shelf [p4a](http://inclem.net/files/p4a_revamp_doc/old_toolchain/android.html#module-android.broadcast) broadcast receiver does not have the bluetooth state broadcast receiver built in.  You have to amend the source and add support for BluetoothAdapter state.

After my first build of the kivy app using `buildozer android debug deploy`.  I go to the following directory `/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/src/android/broadcast.py` and amend the code with the following:

```
def _expand_partial_name(partial_name):
            if '.' in partial_name:
                return partial_name  # Its actually a full dotted name
            else:
                name = 'ACTION_{}'.format(partial_name.upper())

                if hasattr(Intent, name):
                    return getattr(Intent, name)
                elif hasattr(BluetoothAdapter, name):
                    return getattr(BluetoothAdapter, name)
                else:
                    raise Exception('The intent {} doesnt exist'.format(name))

        # resolve actions/categories first
        Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
        BluetoothAdapter = autoclass('android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter')
```

I then run the command `buildozer android clean` and run the build command again.  The p4a broadcast receiver then works as is.  Here is a [working example](https://github.com/Hmerman6006/BluetoothReadInputstream)